# How to get directly to question page in questionnaire plugins

Tags: moodle

I am using the questionnaire plugin version 3.5.4 in the moodle version 3.5.10

In that when i open It showing me as links I want the question direct when i open the questionnaire and same for the response after i submit my answer it will show me the response not the thank you page then responses.In admin account it is fine but i am asking for student accounts. Any Suggestions?

[image: img]

Comment: Can you re-word the question?

Comment: Sorry i didn't understand?

Comment: I don't understand the question :) Can you give examples of what you need to do.

Comment: Well I found the answer "it can't be done" but for your understanding here is the explanation  Actually you see the links in the image i share I want to remove that links from questionnaire plugin in the moodle in "Answer the question" link i put the general question and people going to answer that and their response is stored and when you click on "Your response" link it will show their response to them but i don't want that i just want when i open questionnaire i directly go to question and after finish i see the response not "through links".

Comment: @Russell I don't want the links in Questionnaire Just open that page want a set of questions and when i completed once then next time i open questionnaire page i want the response which i gave earlier but that's not going to happen i got a reply about this from questionnaire plugin developer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point we can't bypass the links in the questionnaire plugin.